# Finding the value of $2^{3x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

> Given $$2^{2x-1}-2^x = 12,$$ find the value of $2^{3x-1}$.

Simpiflying the equation:

$$2^{x}.2^{x}.2^{-1}-2^x = 2^2 \cdot 3$$

This is where I'm stuck.

Regards!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guide:

Let $y = 2^x>0$, then we have $$\frac12 y^2 - y = 12$$

which is just a quadratic equation. Get the positive root.

$$2^{3x-1}=\frac12(2^x)^3=\frac{y^3}2$$

Comment: this method is so confusing. can't we solve it by simpiflying?

Comment: why? where are you stuck?

Comment: @Displayed No, it's easy if you read it well, and it's so unfortunate that I "missed" this easy question (the "fastest gun in the west" rule). $\frac{1}{2}y^2=\frac{2^{2x}}{2}=2^{2x-1}$.

Comment: @Displayed The only possible shortcut is to note that your equation is equivalent to $(2^x−6)(2^x+4)=0$.